# Why procmail couldn't write to temp folder

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, procmail

I use procmail to filter email, but it couldn't write to temp folder:

procmail: Couldn't create or rename temp file "/var/mail/tmp/1483421819.25425_0.morep"
procmail: Assigning "LASTFOLDER=/var/mail/info"

The permission on those mail folders are: mail:mail

What cause the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question lacks the details to properly diagnose this.  Which user is Procmail running as, with what settings?

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  You should use the [contact form](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, they are https://superuser.com/users/681252/jester-pepper and https://superuser.com/users/681515/robot-pepper.  You’ll then be able to [edit], comment on, and accept answers to this question.

Comment: Also posted as a cross-site duplicate (closed as unclear, yet much clearer than this one) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216429/why-procmail-keep-saying-it-cant-write-to-tmp-dir

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to use `/var/mail` itself as a maildir folder.  I cannot imagine a situation where this makes sense.

Normally, `/var/mail` should contain a bunch of personal mbox folders, each named after its owner.  You would obviously then configure Procmail to write mbox (not maildir) format to this location.  For example,

```
:0:
/var/mail/$USER
```

(where $USER is the name of the account, and the file must be a regular file, or not exist).  Though this is probably already the compiled-in default action, so you don't need an explicit recipe for this. (You can run `procmail -v` to see what the default mailbox for the current user is.)

Anyway, if you think you want maildir to work, you need to have a directory named `/var/mail/tmp` which is writable by the user whose Procmail instance is trying to deliver to this location. (For proper Maildir functionality, there should be directories named `cur` and `new`, too, with similar permissions.)

More commonly, you would have a maildir structure with the correct permissions etc in the user's home directory (or some approximation, for virtual users) and write there instead.

Comment: See also http://www.iki.fi/era/procmail/mini-faq.html#appendix-folders for a brief review of supported folder formats.